# Como puedo declarar el width y height de una card en bootstrap?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

```
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
          <div class="col">



              <a href="lawea.html"><div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img" alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
                  <p>Hotel del luna</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              </a>



          </div>
          <div class="col">
              <div class="card bg-dark text-white ">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img" alt="..." >
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end " >
                  <h6 class="card-title">3 Days </h6>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col ">
              <div class="card bg-dark text-white ">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img" alt="..." >
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
                  <h6 class="card-title">A Better Tomorrow</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
```

intento que todo tengan el mismo tamaño de un ancho de 340px y 480px de alto , intenté agregar width="340" height="480" a las etiquetas img pero se quedan del tamaño de la imagen de origen , tambien intenté darle un style en mi head pero no cambió nada

Comment: Saludos. Le sugiero use el **Grid System** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ para que su código sea responsivo; sin embargo, si su intención es ponerlo fijo, haga el cambio en `style` del tag respectivo y agrega a cada dato/valor `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, puedes hacerlo a través del atributo `style` de la siguiente manera:

```
        <div class="card bg-dark text-white " style="width: 300px">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img" alt="..." >
            <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
              <h6 class="card-title">A Better Tomorrow</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
```

También puedes crear una clase personalizada y asignar el width en ella, ejemplo:

```
.card-personalizada {
    width: 300px
}

// En el html
<div class="card card-personalizada bg-dark text-white">
...
```

ó también puedes aprovechar las clases del grid de bootstrap (`col-3, col-6` etc...), colocando un width a la columna en lugar de a la carta:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white ">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img"
                    alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
                    <h6 class="card-title">A Better Tomorrow</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white ">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img"
                    alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
                    <h6 class="card-title">A Better Tomorrow</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white ">
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fe/e1/84/fee18481df61ce4220956dc8f44d09e8.jpg" class="card-img"
                    alt="...">
                <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
                    <h6 class="card-title">A Better Tomorrow</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```